# how to do this using properties of definite integrals?

Tags: calculus

$$\int_1^2 ln_2(x^3+1)dx$$

which is the same as

$\int_1^2 ln_2((3)-(x^3+1))dx$

which gives $\int_1^2 ln_2(2-x^3)\ dx$

which does not help.

Or integrate this by parts, but that's really tedious.

Comment: Integration by parts seems to be the easiest method. You can also use $x^3+1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ to split the integral into $2$ somewhat easier ones, and then integrate them both by parts. The first integral isn't the same as the second. The integrand isn't even well defined for the second(for example, for $x=3$, the integrand is $2-9=-7$)

Comment: It's log base 2, not ln(2)

Comment: The base doesn't matter, you can change to $\ln$ with the base change formula

Comment: oh, by split, you meant using ln(ab)=ln(a)+ln(b)?

Comment: Yes, like David did below. Apparently I messed up the factorization of $x^3+1$ a bit

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $x^3 + 1 = (x+1)(1 - x + x^2)$.

$$\int\limits_{x=1}^2 \log_2 (x^3 + 1)\ dx = \int\limits_{x=1}^2 \log_2 (x + 1)\ dx +\int\limits_{x=1}^2 \log_2 (1 - x + x^2)\ dx$$

Then use (from integral tables): $\int \log_2 (x+1)\ dx = (x+1) \log (x+1)-x$

and

$\int \log_2 (1 - x + x^2)\ dx = \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log \left(x^2-x+1\right)-2 x+\sqrt{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2
   x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$

sum, to find the full integral is:

$$\frac{1}{6} \left(\sqrt{3} \pi +27 \log_2 (3)-6 (3+\log_2 (4))\right)$$